# Constantly monitor bitcoin wallet using Python/Django?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

I am building a site with python/django, running bitcoind in the background. I need to constantly check all addresses in the wallet to do a sql insert statement to my database whenever an incoming transaction is received, and maybe send some funds out in certain cases.

My site is working ok, and I wrote a python script that runs separate and uses a simple while true loop to achieve this. The problem is, when the script is running, it takes up too much memory and the site times out when I reload it. How to avoid this? I really need a background process running at all times. I am trying to use threading in the script, but it still seems to hog too much memory.

I thought about running bitcoind with the same wallet and the script on a separate computer, but I heard that is a bad idea.

Thanks.

Comment: I have written a Python framework for dealing issues like this in cryptocurrencies: https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets - it comes even with open source example applications for Django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [wallet notify](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=203438.0). You can set it in your `bitcoin.conf` file and have it call some python or django script.

Or another solution would be to constantly poll for new transactions, though I would not recommend this.

Comment: Thank you, this helped immensely. Exactly what I needed! Unfortunately, when I call walletnotify= python /path/to/script %s, it passes 'sh: 1: <txid> could not find 32512' into sys.argv[1]. However, if I pass it to a C++ program, it just passes the txid. So strange.

Comment: weird, though shouldn't it be `sys.argv[2]`?

Comment: It said that was out of index. Also, it works in C++ just fine. I don't know, I will mess with it more and try to get it working. I don't have any quotations in my -walletnotify command.